# select living-end-streets from a local osm-road-extract with QGIS

Tags: qgis, query, select-by-attribute, select-by-location

I am looking for a method or query to select [living-end-streets](http://www.pedestrians-int.org/images/IFP/pdf/Living_end_roads_-_concept_note.pdf) from a local osm-road-extract.

Living-end-streets are dead-end-streets for cars but cyclists and pedestrians can continue on their way.

So I want to select roads that share their endpoint with one (ore more) "highway"  IN  ( 'footway' , 'footpath' ,'steps', 'cycleway','pedestrian','track','bridleway') but NO other highway types.

Preconditions are:

- Preferrable Using built-in functionalities or plugins from QGIS 2.14 or later
- No PostGIS
- Only python if no other solution is possible - <s>like it seems to be</s>

Eg:
[image]

Comment: Not totally sure, but I think this one might need python! I'll be interested to see if anyone can come up with a QGIS only solution...

Comment: @Matt It seems you're right about the use of python, I will change the preconditions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution without python and postgis, using the graphical modeller.

Here is a summarized explanation.

**Step 1:**

- extract end nodes with v.to.point
- give them a unique id
- give them a new attribute roadtype based on following expression

> case when highway IN
>   ('path','footway','footpath','steps','cycleway','pedestrian','track','bridleway')
>   then 1 else 2 end

**Step 2:** do a fixed distance buffer on the endnodes with distance = 0.01

**Step 3:** do extract by attribute on the endnodes based on the values given in step 1

**Step 4:**

- twice count points in polygon based on step 2 and step 3
- join both tables based on the newID given in step 1

**Step 5:**

- evaluate the counting based on following expression,

> ```
> case when snel = 1 and traag >= 1 then 1 else 0 end
> ```

Meaning: evaluate buffer with only 1 endpoint from segment allowed by car and 1 or more endpoints from segments just for cyclists or pedestrians.

- extract the buffers who are evaluated as '1'

**Step 6:** extract those roads that intersect with the buffers from step 5

[image]

**! One important footnote:**

this model does not extract roads with a turningcircle at the end, although they are in fact living-end-streets.
[image]

Comment: Very nicely done! +1